# How does address bar tracking work?

Tags: language-agnostic

Services like [AddThis](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381254-address-bar-sharing-analytics#.Uh1bOmRxuQg) go into superficial detail about how their services work, but I would be really grateful to hear some insight into how this is actually working.

If this is an inappropriate forum to ask this question in, feel free to yell at me - I'm trying to get a handle on how to detect when users are interacting with their address bar, but am hitting a solid brick wall. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Ask their developers instead of asking here.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor - it is an easily replicated technique that anyone interested in detecting "manual" sharing might be interested in. Seems like a reasonable question that could lead to some helpful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the page loads without a hash "tag" appended to the URL, the AddThis code generates a new, unique one and appends it to the URL.  If the user, then cuts and pastes the URL, sharing it manually in some other forum - like Twitter, the unique tag specifically identifies which user (assuming he/she can be detected on the first page load) shared the article this way whenever that particular link is used by someone else.  The normal AddThis sharing does not include the hash "tag" and thus the manual sharing is distinguishable from the user clicking on the share button.

While I haven't looked at their implementation in detail (debugging in the web browser would probably produce a lot of insight), I suspect that they obtain the unique id from their servers to guarantee uniqueness and tie it in with their other analytic data.

Comment: thanks so much for your answer. To clarify, each time the link is clicked, is AddThis's (or whatever other service) server being tapped to let them know that someone clicked on the link? I think I'm trying to think about this in the way that Constant Contact tracks emails, but maybe that's wrong.

Comment: Yep - there's undoubtedly a bit of JavaScript on the page that reads the hash "tag" and logs it on AddThis' servers.